# What are the limits for broadband (BB) and narrowband (NB) radiated emissions?

Tags: emc

I am looking at [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ta/sszt671/sszt671.pdf?ts=1710501774139&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to learn more about RE testing.

It says:

> Figure 1 provides limits for broadband (BB) and narrowband (NB) radiated emissions over the applicable frequency range of
> 30MHz to 1GHz "

Figure 1 is given below.

[image]

This document does not say anything about limits for broadband (BB) and narrowband (NB).

- What are the frequency ranges for broadband (BB) and narrow-band (NB) emissions?
- What is the significance of broadband (BB) and narrow-band (NB) emissions?

Comment: The document you referenced is a review (summary). It has links to the full specifications that you must follow. Please read the full spec and ask a more detailed question.

Comment: It all depends on what the actual bandwidths are for NB and BB emissions testing.  They should be defined for you.

Comment: Note also that the definition of bandwidth (either NB or BB) may vary depending on where you are in the frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document shows two graphs, you only posted one. The left one is concerning "broadband" and the right one is concerning "narrowband". These are directly taken from the referenced UNECE R10 document (automotive EMC regulation), Appendix 2.

As for how to interpret the graphs:

Note that documents like this always (ought to) specify either a peak and/or an average limit. Essentially how the EMC test is carried out: is the spectrum analyser put on "max hold" (quasi peak) or just collecting an average? Peak limits are often harder to pass.

The dBuV/m unit doesn't really tell the average designer much, it's a strange unit for everyone except those living and breathing EMC testing (but can be converted to dBm with a bit of physics formula head ache). As a designer, you kind of just need to know that automotive EMC is slightly tougher than regular industrial EMC, much tougher than commercial EMC, but not nearly as tough as aerospace/military. Then put in your counter-measure efforts accordingly. Because you will not likely be able to measure if your DUT passes or not outside an EMC lab.

The frequency range is very relevant for the designer though, as you need to adapt your filters accordingly.

Comment: Thank you."Essentially how the EMC test is carried out: is the spectrum analyser put on "max hold" (quasi peak) or just collecting an average? Peak limits are often harder to pass." Does this mean spectrum analyzer is kept on quasi peak and they are measuring average value

Comment: @Hari Quasi peak is some EMC test term where a peak detector is used together with some manner of damping, I'm far from an expert at this so wikipedia can explain it better. For the average electrical engineer, just think of it as a fancy form of the "max hold" function that you got on your spectrum analyzer. Also, exactly how every EMC test is carried out is very strictly regulated and the test engineers at the lab has to study those requirements in-depth. Why the majority of the EMC report is always about instruments and DUT rigging, rather than the actual results.